# Counting candies in boxes

Tags: combinatorics

There are $5$ boxes containing $80$ candies. After taking $\frac{1}{5}$ of the candies in the first box and putting them in the seconf one, we take  $\frac{1}{5}$ of the candies in the second box and putting them in the third one (after we added the $\frac{1}{5}$ candies from the first box) and so on untill we take $\frac{1}{5}$ of the candies in the fifth box and put it in the first one.
After this process, each box contained the smae number of candies.  How many candies were initially in each box?

So I can say $a+b+c+d+e=80$ and then slowly and brutally start calculating how many candies were in each box after the process- which will yield 6 equations (including the first one). But is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

We have: $\dfrac{4a}{5} + \dfrac{e}{5} = \dfrac{a}{5} + \dfrac{4b}{5} = \dfrac{b}{5} + \dfrac{4c}{5} = \dfrac{c}{5} + \dfrac{4d}{5} = \dfrac{d}{5} + \dfrac{4e}{5}= \dfrac{80}{5} = 16$, and $a+b+c+d+e=80$. Can you solve this system?

Comment: How did you get there? We took $\frac{1}{%}$ from each box only after we put $\frac{1}{%}$ from the previous one

Comment: I mean you took $1/5$ from one box and add $1/5$ to the same box from another box.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we know for sure:

- $n$ candies were taken from the $1$st box and put into the $2$nd box
- $4$ candies were taken from the $2$nd box and put into the $3$rd box
- $4$ candies were taken from the $3$rd box and put into the $4$th box
- $4$ candies were taken from the $4$th box and put into the $5$th box
- $4$ candies were taken from the $5$th box and put into the $1$st box

Hence:

- $b_1-n+4=16$
- $b_2+n-4=16$
- $b_3+4-4=16$
- $b_4+4-4=16$
- $b_5+4-4=16$

Hence:

- $b_1=12+n$
- $b_2=20-n$
- $b_3=16$
- $b_4=16$
- $b_5=16$

Hence:

- $5|(12+n)$
- $n\leq20$

Hence $n$ must be equal to $3$ or $8$ or $13$ or $18$.

So you can simply check each of these options, and find the remaining initial values...

Answer (score 0):

Boxes $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ each contain $16$ candies at the end, and this is after they gave away ${1\over5}$ of their intermediary content. It follows that these four boxes each contained $20$ candies after receiving candies from their predecessor. Arguing about box $A$ now gives
$$16={4\over5} a+ 4\>,$$
or $a=15$, which then immediately leads to $b=17$, $c=d=e=16$.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion:

Can you work backwards?  At the end the distribution is $(16,16,16,16,16)$.  The step before, the distribution would be $(12,16,16,16,20)$.